# JWT.decode is returning nil unless validation is set to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I'm following the Auth0 blog for decoding a JWT and I'm trying to grab the user information from it.

[Create a web token class](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/rails/01-authorization#create-a-jsonwebtoken-class)
def self.verify(token)

```
    decoded_token = JWT.decode(token, nil,
               true, # Verify the signature of this token
               algorithms: 'RS256',
               iss: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/',
               verify_iss: true,
               aud: Rails.application.secrets.auth0_api_audience,
               verify_aud: true) do |header|
      jwks_hash[header['kid']]
    end
  end
```

But when I inspect `decoded_token` its **nil**.

[Looking at the jwt gem, in decode I see](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt#algorithms-and-usage%5D):

```
# Set password to nil and validation to false otherwise this won't work
decoded_token = JWT.decode token, nil, false
```

So I changed `true` to `false` in the auth0 code and I can see the pertinent user data that I need.

```
(byebug) decoded_token
[{"email"=>"xxx@example.com", "iss"=>"https://example.com/", "sub"=>"auth0|123456", "aud"=>["https://example.com", "https://example.auth0.com/userinfo"], "iat"=>123456, "exp"=>123456, "azp"=>"123456abc", "scope"=>"openid profile email"}, {"alg"=>"RS256", "typ"=>"JWT", "kid"=>"abcdefg"}]
```

I don't fully understand the code, what is happening here.  Seems like I would want to keep verification on right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token is invalid. At the very least the issuer (`iss`) doesn't match (and you've specifically set `verify_iss: true`) and the expiration claim (`exp`) is (very far) in the past, which automatically invalidates a JWT.

If you give an invalid token to `decode` and specify that it should validate its input, it returns `nil`, per its documentation.

> Seems like I would want to keep verification on right?

Yes. You certainly want to reject invalid tokens.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip.  I think it's been failing silently when nil leading me to think the tokens have been valid.  I'll do some more investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I awarded **user229044** with the right answer because they were correct, the token was invalid, but wanted to add context for anyone who may run into something similar.

1. Check your env vars.  The problem turned out to be the string interpolation in  json_web_token.rb: `iss: "https://#{Rails.application.credentials.auth0[:DOMAIN]}/",` and in the domain in the env file also included the full domain (including https://), so JWT.decode was looking for `https://https.//...` and the issuer was invalid.  This was hard to see because the env vars matched my frontend 100% so cross checking those didn't help.
2. I had littered my call stack with byebugs trying to figure this out which messed with the implicit returns in ruby.  The decoded token should be available in your **secured_controller.rb** as it gets returned implicitly in **authorization_service.rb** and **json_web_token.rb**.